# Dataframe nested dictionary to multi-index dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

First to construct a simplified version of my question dataset, this is only helping to create a sample, I only have the final nest_dict on hand. Meaning I dont have dfs separately:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'val':{'a': 1, 'b':2, 'c':3}})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'val':{'a': 3, 'b':4, 'c':1}})
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'val':{'a': 2, 'b':1, 'c':4}})
dfs = [df1, df2, df3]
dates = ['2017-01-26','2017-02-03','2017-02-10']
nest_dict = {}
for date, d in zip(dates, dfs):
        nest_dict[date] = d
```

I would like to convert it to a **Multi-Index Dataframe.**

```
date1 a val1
      b val2
      c val3
date2 a val1
      b val2
      c val3
....
```

Its basically a dataframe with a date as key, it could easily become a panel, but since its been deprecated, how would I transform it to a multiindex dataframe?
I did try following, but it does not work:

```
d = {(key, item) for key, item in corr_SH50.items()}
TypeError: 'DataFrame' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed
```

Comment: What kind of MultiIndex are you expecting?

Comment: Thanks for replying. I would like the date be the primary index, and a,b,c be secondary index.

Comment: later, i will need to use pivotal table to add different dates' value up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

concat with keys:

```
pd.concat(dfs,keys=dates)
```

---

```
              val
2017-01-26 a    1
           b    2
           c    3
2017-02-03 a    3
           b    4
           c    1
2017-02-10 a    2
           b    1
           c    4
```

Comment: I don't have access to dfs though, its only helping to create a nested dictionary. I only have the final nest_dict on hand

Comment: @user14384765 even better: `pd.concat(nest_dict)` would also work then